# What is the correct way to transfer data between chrome extension files?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

*I am new to developing extensions for chrome. My task is to write an extension that takes data from a music-player web page and passes it to Discord-RPC*

The *music.yandex.ru* page has a built-in function for extensions, that returns information about the current track:  `externalAPI.getCurrentTrack();`, but the the problem is that in order to access this function, I have to use a *"MAIN" world* type in the **3rd version** of the manifest, from which I can't pass data to my extension and then send it to the [RPC] server.

I've read a lot of information about injecting scripts on a page, but I've never been able to send the data back to my extension local world.

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Yandex-RPC",
  "description": "-",
  "version": "1.0",
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "world": "MAIN",
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "matches": ["https://music.yandex.ru/*"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "nativeMessaging",
    "scripting"
  ]
}
```

**content.js**

```
// Wait for the Yandex.Music external API to be ready
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  if (typeof externalAPI !== "undefined") {
    // Send the current track information to the extension popup
    function sendTrackInfo(trackInfo) {
      console.log(trackInfo);
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "trackInfo", data: trackInfo });
    }

    // Listen for changes in the track
    externalAPI.on(externalAPI.EVENT_TRACK, function() {
      const track = externalAPI.getCurrentTrack();
      if (track) {
        sendTrackInfo(track);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

**popup.js**

```
function updatePopup(trackInfo) { ... }

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (message.action === "trackInfo") {
    updatePopup(message.data);
  }
});
```

When running the script I get an error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sendMessage')` - which means that the content.js function does not have access to the browser's local world.

I have read the chrome documentation but it seems too confusing; and also I found some examples of implementing the script on manifest v2, but this version is already outdated.

**How do I use service_worker or chrome.scripting to send the received data to popup.js?**

Comment: The example you provided shows how to link scripts in the local extension world, when calling the global function I get an error: Error in event handler: `ReferenceError: externalAPI is not defined`. If I switch the content script to _"MAIN" world type_, I can't use chrome.runtime.* and get `Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist` . **I need a way that includes these two options.**

Comment: Inject an iframe into web page. And the content script communicates with it.